# Continue for loop in python after crash?

Tags: python, for-loop, pandas, iterator

I have a for loop in python that goes like:

```
for index, row in sqlResults.iterrows();
   doSomething(row)
```

At one point, there was a connectivity issue and this crashed. However, it's now working. Is there a way I can just cotinue the loop? I don't want to call it from the start of sqlResults.iterrows() again?

Here sqlResults is a pandas dataframe.

Comment: Do you mean that this was in a script that crashed, and now you want to restart the script, but continue from where the previous run left off? Or do you

Comment: I piped it from ELPY to the console. So now, in my emacs window the left side is the code the right side is the console. On the right side I can issue python commands and moreover check things like `row`

Comment: Well, try running those two lines again; if you're lucky, it'll continue from where it left off. Otherwise, I think you may be out of luck. Though you might be able to determine which rows were seen based on whatever `doSomething()` is doing.